# Creating Multiple Excel sheets using data frames Python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to create Multiple Excel sheets using Python Pandas But its only creating the latest one and old one is getting replaced. Here my Scan2 Replaces Scan1 Sheet in output.xlsx file it's not saving the sheets.

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#scan1
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/t/Downloads/a.csv")

dfdf = df[df["Data"].str.contains("None") == False]

dfdf.to_excel("output.xlsx" , sheet_name= 'scan1' , index = False )

#scan2

dfg = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/t/Downloads/b.csv")

dfdfd = dfg[df["Data"].str.contains("None") == False]

dfdfd.to_excel("output.xlsx" , sheet_name= 'Scan2' , index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save multiple sheets to excel, you have to use pandas' ExcelWriter method

try this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

dfdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Scan01')
dfdfd.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Scan02')
```

other way of doing it without ExcelWriter installation:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
     dfdf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Scan01')
     dfdfd.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Scan02')
```

Comment: Scripts runs successfully but file is not getting opened it seems like corrupted.

Comment: Thanks the second method is working fine able to create 2 sheets . But the operation to cut the None row of 2nd sheet is not working is there anything that i missed. @Niqua